# User IP address and location in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, json, database, laravel-5, ip-address

I am trying to get the ip address and location of user during registration...when user sign up for the first time I want to save the ip address and his location in the database in users table.

Please give me a solution to get the ip address and location of the new user...

**Below is the line which i am using but this gives me wrong IP address of localhost...**

```
127.0.0.1

$user = new User([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'company' => $data['company'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'country' => $data['country'],
        'zipcode' => $data['zipcode'],
        'city' => $data['city'],
        'state' => $data['state'] == "other" ? $data['custom_state'] : $data['state'],
        'ip_address' => request()->ip(),
    ]);
```

Comment: `'ip_addres' => \Request::ip(),` Check this

Comment: FYI - I was getting my localhost ip address too while working locally, but once on a remote server the ip() method returned the expected results.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this to get the ip address of user:

```
'ip_address' => \Request::ip();
```

and after getting an ip address you can get the location from that ip using below package.

https://github.com/stevebauman/location

```
'position' = Location::get(ip_address);
```

---

In the case of you get the localhost ip address then use this package to solve it: https://packagist.org/packages/fideloper/proxy

Comment: hmm i try find wait

Comment: i am using this fideloper package but still getting the local host ip..not my original ip.

Comment: If an user use a ip changer , what will happen ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    } else {
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    }
    $json     = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/$ipaddress/geo");
    $json     = json_decode($json, true);
    $country  = $json['country'];
    $region   = $json['region'];
    $city     = $json['city'];
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.